# Harvesting Basil Seeds Too Early

Tags: seeds, germination, basil

I harvested Thai Basil seeds, but I cut off the flowering bud portion of the plant before it was entirely dried, though it was done flowering.  The seeds are a whitish color instead of the typical black that I see when others harvest when dried.

If a basil seed is harvested too early, will they still grow, or is it required that they be fully dried?

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is, the seed may not be fully mature, meaning it may not have completed its developent. That means it won't grow, but you've nothing to lose by trying anyway. When the basil flowers again, wait longer to harvest those seeds.